# SQL-query takes a lot longer time in code than query db direct

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a SQL query that takes less than a second to execute when I'm using SQL Management Studio, but when my code executes it, it takes over 30 seconds to get the result from the database server. The result contains 1700 rows. Another similar query, that returns 900 rows, takes a few ms to execute. What can be the reason for this odd behaviour?

```
    public SqlDataReader ExecuteReader(string strSQL, ArrayList arParams)
    {
        OpenConnection();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, myConnection);
        myCommand.CommandTimeout = intTimeout;


        foreach (SqlParameter myParameter in arParams)
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(myParameter);

        return myCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
```

strSQL:

```
SELECT [Group].[Id]
       ,[Group].[intCustomerId]   
       ,[Group].[strName]
       ,[Permission].[dtmCreated]
       ,[Permission].[intPermissionTypeId]
       ,[Permission].[intObjectTypeId]          
       ,[Permission].[intObjectId]            
       ,[Permission].[blnActive]            
       ,[Permission].[blnHaveAccess]
       ,[Permission].[intLevelTypeId]             
 FROM [Group]
 LEFT JOIN Permission ON [Group].[Id] = intGroupId AND 
                         intObjectId = @ObjectId AND 
                         intObjectTypeId = @ObjectTypeId AND 
                         intLevelTypeId = @LevelType AND
                         intPermissionTypeId = @PermissionTypeId AND
                         blnActive = 1                                             
 WHERE [Group].[intCustomerId] = @CustomerId  AND
       [Group].[blnDeleted] = 0
 ORDER BY strName, blnActive DESC
```

arParams:

```
arParams.Add(DatabaseHandler.MakeSqlParameter("@CustomerId", customer.Id));
arParams.Add(DatabaseHandler.MakeSqlParameter("@ObjectId", masterprocess.Id));
arParams.Add(DatabaseHandler.MakeSqlParameter("@ObjectTypeId", Convert.ToInt32(ObjectType.MasterProcess)));
arParams.Add(DatabaseHandler.MakeSqlParameter("@PermissionTypeId", Convert.ToInt32(permissiontype)));
arParams.Add(DatabaseHandler.MakeSqlParameter("@LevelType", Convert.ToInt32(leveltype)));
```

DatabaseHandler.MakeSqlParameter:

```
public static SqlParameter MakeSqlParameter(String strName, int intInput)
{
    return new SqlParameter(strName, intInput);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642453/sql-query-and-datetime-parameter-takes-long-time-to-execute & an answer by @gbn. I suppose, it could be data type of SQLParameters that is not in sync with what SQL expects. For e.g. the parameter type of one or more of SQLParameter could be varchar whereas it should be an int (as SQL would expect it).

Comment: It might be a case of "parameter sniffing", however for that to apply: Is `strSQL` the literal query or is it the name of some stored procedure that calls the query internally? Do you test with the same parameter values in both cases?

Comment: Perhaps post if that box has enough ram ? What does SQL management tool say about current Rescource waits?

Comment: @Christian.K strSQL is the literal query. I do the test with same parameters

Comment: @EKS: Rescource waits says 0, but the processor time reach 100% when I run the query from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reply on comments i would say the correct solution is indexes.

Simplest way would be to run the sql logging for a bit when you run the normal queries, and then afterward run the run the sql profiler.

Based on its recommendations it could have spottet a missing indexes.

Comment: You seem to pushed me in the right direction. I found out that i could rebuild the indexes, witch i did on my Permission table, and now it runs in normal speed. Still dont understand why running the query in management studio goes so much faster than running it in the code tho.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but thought of the solution while looking at this question.

When you run the query using SQLCommand with Parameters, the query is NOT executed the same. It uses a stored procedure helper to package the parameters. Something like Exec sp_Execute.

If you do the parameter replacing you should notice an improvement (I know there is a risk of SQL injection then).

Also you can go even further and specify WITH(INDEX) next to your table to specify which index you want to use. (Because it might try and use the PK index).