# Correct work with MS SQL

Tags: c#, database, dataadapter

I have a program that gets data from SQL server table. The code is the following:

```
SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(...);//correct
conn.Open();
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
SqlCommand selectCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Condition", conn);
SqlDataAdapter custDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
custDA.SelectCommand = selectCMD;
custDA.Fill(dt);
Datagridview1.DataSource=dt;
Datagridview1.DataBind();
```

But the problem is that when executing the same query in SQL server management studio, it takes less then second to execute. Meanwhile when using program, it takes half a minute to get the result. Using debugger I see, that the main row, where program "thinks" a lot time is when data adapter is filling DataTable. Any suggestions how to reduce the time? What's wrong in my code?

Comment: How many rows are returned by your Query ?

Comment: Does your application uses roles or something that can take considerable time that is not related to this issue?

Comment: That is when the time would be taken as the query is not executed until the data is requested. I can't explain why it's slower than Management Studio but that is why it's slow at the `Fill` call. If this is not where your time is being taken up its not related to the SQL

Comment: My application does not use any roles. The query may return no rows, one row or many rows

Comment: @SoneshDabhi thanks, I will have a look, but I am not using stored procedures or user defined functions as such.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL-query takes a lot longer time in code than query db direct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7427475/sql-query-takes-a-lot-longer-time-in-code-than-query-db-direct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank Everyone for help. I used parameters in `SqlCommand` object. Unfortunately I haven't mentioned that so you couldn't help me. But as [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james) posted a link, I have found that when `SqlCommand` is uded with parameters then the execution is made using stored procedure `sp_execute`. Because server has to compile it, that's why it takes so long. After parameters were removed, everything is working good. The other way is that you can turn off automatic recomplilation each time stored procedure executes. Thanks everyone again. +1 for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Managaement studio just displays text results.  `SqlDataAdapter` must map each result column value to a `DataGridView` column value.  One will take much more time than the other.  With Management Studio, it also virtualizes the results--it doesn't show all the results at once as you scroll down for large result sets more data is retrieved.

Comment: With single row the same situation. Is that really because of datagridview?

Comment: Really, a single row takes 30 seconds?  There's something else going on there because I've *never* run into something like that.

Comment: Maybe if that's matter, the table has over two millions rows. But I'm using indexes - and SQL management studio is executing this query fast.

Comment: What happens if you change the query to `"SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TABLE WHERE Condition"`?  If you're only getting one row back, the time *isn't* the mapping of data--it`s SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

You can to create index and to set options to accelerate query execution. And you can to use this approach to load data [SqlDataAdapter.Fill - Asynchronous approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108917/sqldataadapter-fill-asynchronous-approach)

```
create index condition_idx on table (condition)

new SqlCommand("set nocount on;SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Condition", conn);
```

Comment: And `set nocount` and `Asynchronous approach`?. The answer to you question is what @PeterRitchie said, the solution is a combination of factors.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you might need proper indexing on required columns . When you are running query from SQL it might be using an execution plan which is more optimized compared to when .Fill method is doing .

Can you try cleaning out procedure cache and memory buffers using SSMS:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

Doing so before you test your query prevents usage of cached execution plans and previous results cache.

Comment: I tried. There was slight slowdown - well the query was executed in 4 seconds. But not a minute.

Comment: There is index on the field that is used in where clause